# How to count wish-list item by productid?

Tags: magento-1.9, wishlist

I want to count the wish list item to know about the popularity of that particular product

Comment: Please add more details. What is the desired result? What did you try?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this  by ***calling Collection model*** of `wishlist/item`.

At *`wishlist_item`* table ,there it has a field named **`product_id`**,by which you can filter the collection.

> ```
> $collection=Mage::getResourceModel('wishlist/item_collection');
> $collection->addFieldToFilter('product_id',$productId);
> ```

Comment: its giving blank page